# How to set hot corners on a second display

Tags: settings, display, hot-corners

I want a "multitasking view" hotcorner on my second monitor, but the hot corner settings only give the options to set them for my primary display.

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: This ia a bug in elementary. You can find it here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1385296 as well as here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/gala/+bug/1080283

Comment: Not so sure about that. It's still unclear to me whether it's a bug or a design choice.

Answer (score 6):

It seems that as of now, elementary designs hot-corners to work like wingpanel and the dock and show them only on the primary display.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1385296
https://bugs.launchpad.net/gala/+bug/1080283